# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Objects not supported in a DAC geography

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dacpac, data-tier-applications

Using SQL Server Management Studio, I'm trying to create a DACPAC by right-clicking the `db -> Tasks -> Extract Data-Tier Application`.  When I get to the Validation and Summary screen I get some errors because sql spatial data types aren't supported.  I've read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210549(v=sql.105).aspx) and it lists the `SQL Server Data Types` supported in DAC and Spatial Types aren't. Is there a workaround to this so I can create a DACPAC with SQL spatial data types in my tables?

Here is the error shown in the wizard:

```
DAC Objects
     ---Objects not supported in a DAC
             [my table name] - Column '[Location]' is of type 'geography', 'geometry', or 'hierarchyid', which are not supported in a data-tier application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of SSMS Preview should support spatial data types when extracting.  It's available for download here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx